# Binding a generic list to a repeater - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am trying to bind a `List<AreaField>` to a repeater. I have converted the list into an array by using the `ToArray()` method and now have a array of `AreaField[]`

Here's my class hierarchy

```
public class AreaFields
{
    public List<Fields> Fields { set; get; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Value {set; get; }
}
```

In the aspx, I would like to bind it a repeater (something like this)

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyAreaFieldName1")
```

The MyAreaFieldName1 is the value of the Name property in the AreaFieldItem class.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may want to create a subRepeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="SubRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Fields") %>'>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <span><%# Eval("Name") %></span>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You can also cast your fields

```
<%# ((ArrayFields)Container.DataItem).Fields[0].Name %>
```

Finally you could do a little CSV Function and write out your fields with a function

```
<%# GetAsCsv(((ArrayFields)Container.DataItem).Fields) %>

public string GetAsCsv(IEnumerable<Fields> fields)
{
  var builder = new StringBuilder();
  foreach(var f in fields)
  {
    builder.Append(f);
    builder.Append(",");
  }
  builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1);
  return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: runat="SubRepeater"?!? -- that defies all I understand (or think I understand) about the runat attribute.

Comment: Your sub-repeater code as-is gives a parser error, should be single-quotes: DataSource='<%# Eval("Fields") %>'.

Answer (score 65):

It is surprisingly simple...

Code behind:

```
// Here's your object that you'll create a list of
private class Products
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductPrice { get; set; }
}

// Here you pass in the List of Products
private void BindItemsInCart(List<Products> ListOfSelectedProducts)
{   
    // The the LIST as the DataSource
    this.rptItemsInCart.DataSource = ListOfSelectedProducts;

    // Then bind the repeater
    // The public properties become the columns of your repeater
    this.rptItemsInCart.DataBind();
}
```

ASPX code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItemsInCart" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Description</th>
            <th>Product Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><%# Eval("ProductName") %></td>
      <td><%# Eval("ProductDescription")%></td>
      <td><%# Eval("ProductPrice")%></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: PS: struct can be used instead of class.

Comment: This is great. Note that Header and Footer template are not needed if they are not templated. Will make the opening and closing html parse more cleanly if you put these as raw html before and after the repeater.

Comment: If you forget to make the variables in class Products public then it won't work. I made that mistake.

Answer (score 6):

Code Behind:

```
public class Friends
{
    public string   ID      { get; set; }
    public string   Name    { get; set; }
    public string   Image   { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List <Friends> friendsList = new List<Friends>();

        foreach (var friend  in friendz)
        {
            friendsList.Add(
                new Friends { ID = friend.id, Name = friend.name }    
            );

        }

        this.rptFriends.DataSource = friendsList;
        this.rptFriends.DataBind();
}
```

---

.aspx Page

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFriends" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%# Eval("ID") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
                    </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use ToList() method. 
(Don't forget about System.Linq namespace)

ex.:

```
IList<Model> models = Builder<Model>.CreateListOfSize(10).Build();
List<Model> lstMOdels = models.ToList();
```