# convert List<ListItem> to datatable in c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

In my application I need to fetch items from 2 SharePoint lists(ListA & ListB) as a listitem-collection and then I need to show items from ListA if the items in ListB matchs (ListA.empid == ListB.empid).

```
var iPs = AListItem.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(r => r.FieldValues["EmpID"])
                   .Union(BListItem.AsEnumerable()
                                   .Select(r => r.FieldValues["EmpID"]));

if (iPs.Count() > 0)
{
    List<ListItem> sample = (from row in AListItem.AsEnumerable()
                             join id in iPs
                             on row.FieldValues["EmpID"] equals id
                             select row).ToList();
}
```

But i need result in datatable in order to bind to repeater control. How can I convert `List<ListItem>` to datatable?

Comment: Can't you just use the List<ListItem> to bind to the repeater?

Comment: i dontknow how to bind List<ListItem> to repeator control.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, use `sample` as the datasource for the `Repeater` control.

This SO link provides detailed information on how to achieve this:

[binding-a-generic-list-to-a-repeater-asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674204/binding-a-generic-list-to-a-repeater-asp-net)

The overview is this:

```
// Here's your object that you'll create a list of
private class Products
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductPrice { get; set; }
}

// Here you pass in the List of Products
private void BindItemsInCart(List<Products> ListOfSelectedProducts)
{   
    // The the LIST as the DataSource
    this.rptItemsInCart.DataSource = ListOfSelectedProducts;

    // Then bind the repeater
    // The public properties become the columns of your repeater
    this.rptItemsInCart.DataBind();
}
```

ASPX code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItemsInCart" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Description</th>
            <th>Product Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><%# Eval("ProductName") %></td>
      <td><%# Eval("ProductDescription")%></td>
      <td><%# Eval("ProductPrice")%></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Well I didn't read the mysql tag so quickly got rid of it as the syntax is sql server! :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ric: Maybe it's better to bind the List.

But if you really need to convert to a datatable, check these links:

[How to convert a List into DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128140/how-to-convert-a-list-into-datatable)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/list-to-datatable-converter-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: this.ipRepeater.DataSource = sample;
                this.ipRepeater.DataBind(); but it is not working

Comment: is there an error message? Also, see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674204/binding-a-generic-list-to-a-repeater-asp-net)