# Repeater data to excel using Epplus?

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

I am using Epplus to write datatable to excel file which works fine. How can i do this for repeater ?

```
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Repeater class has a property `Data`, so you have to assign your data table to it. The code could look like following

```
    repeater.DataSource = dt; //dt variable is same as in your example
    repeater.DataBind();
```

About why `DataBind` is necessary you can read in: [Why is the DataBind() method necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983981/why-is-the-databind-method-necessary)

Comment: Acutally, i am getting datatable and then manipulating it to a different format by storing them into class object and then binding that item to the repeater which is why i am not able to use "LoadFromDatatable" option of Epplus.

Comment: @siddhipur so why example in your question use this function?

Comment: Anyway if it class of objects look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674204/binding-a-generic-list-to-a-repeater-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

When you say into "class object" I assume you mean a collection of objects?  Which would make sense if you are binding to a repeater.  If so, why not use `LoadFromCollection` instead? Like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void LoadFromCollection_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958463/repeater-data-to-excel-using-epplus
    //Throw in some data
    var dataSet = new List<RowObject>();
    for (var a = 0; a < 20; a++)
        dataSet.Add(new RowObject
        {
            ColumnString = "Row " + a,
            ColumnDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(a)
        });

    //Clear the file
    var newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\Temp.xlsx");
    if (newFile.Exists)
        newFile.Delete();

    var i = 0;
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
    {
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(dataSet, true);

        package.Save();
    }
}

public class RowObject
{
    public string ColumnString { get; set; }
    public DateTime ColumnDateTime { get; set; }
}
```