# How to bind multilevel json data to a repeater in asp.net or converting json data to data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I want to bind the Json data to the repeater I know only one process that is converting the Json data to data table and then binding data but here I am receiving multilevel json data i do't know how to convert them to data table

**input json data:**

```
 {"apiAvailableBuses":
 [{"droppingPoints":null,"availableSeats":40,"partialCancellationAllowed":false,"arrivalTime":"01:00 AM","cancellationPolicy":"[{\"cutoffTime\":\"1\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"10\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"2\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"50\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"4\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]","boardingPoints":[{"time":"07:40PM","location":"K.P.H.B,Beside R.S Brothers","id":"2238"}],"operatorName":"Apple I Bus","departureTime":"8:00 PM","mTicketAllowed":false,"idProofRequired":false,"serviceId":"6686","fare":"1000","busType":"Hi-Tech A/c","routeScheduleId":"6686","commPCT":9.0,"operatorId":203,"inventoryType":0},
 {
 "droppingPoints":null,"availableSeats":41,"partialCancellationAllowed":false,"arrivalTime":"06:00 AM","cancellationPolicy":"[{\"cutoffTime\":\"1\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"10\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"2\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"50\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"4\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]","boardingPoints":[{"time":"08:00PM","location":"Punjagutta,","id":"2241"}],"operatorName":"Royalcoach Travels","departureTime":"8:00 PM","mTicketAllowed":false,"idProofRequired":false,"serviceId":"6736","fare":"800","busType":"VOLVO","routeScheduleId":"6736","commPCT":9.0,"operatorId":243,"inventoryType":0}
```

I am trying to convert it to data table by

```
  public void getavailablebuses()
{



    string url = string.Format(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("files/getavailablebuses.json"));
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {


        string json = client.DownloadString(url);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        string mm = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("apiAvailableBuses").ToString();

     //  var boardingpoint = JObject.Parse(mm).SelectToken("boardingPoints").ToString();
        var Availablebuses = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("apiAvailableBuses").ToString();
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Availablebuses, (typeof(DataTable)));

}
     public class apiresult
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string success { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
  {
    public apiresult apiStatus;
    public List<apiAvailableBuses> apiAvailableBuses{ get; set; }

   // public string apiAvailableBuses { get; set; }

}
public class apiAvailableBuses
{
    public string serviceId { get; set; }
    public string fare { get; set; }
    public string busType { get; set; }
    public string departureTime { get; set; }
    public string operatorName { get; set; }
    public string cancellationPolicy { get; set; }
    public List<boardingpoints> boardingpoints { get; set; }

    public string droppingPoints { get; set; }
    public string inventoryType { get; set; }
    public string routeScheduleId { get; set; }
    public int availableSeats { get; set; }
    public string arrivalTime { get; set; }
    public Boolean idProofRequired { get; set; }
    public Boolean partialCancellationAllowed { get; set; }
    public int operatorId { get; set; }
    public double commPCT { get; set; }
    public string mTicketAllowed { get; set; }

}
public class boardingpoints
{
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }


}
public class cancellationPolicy
{
    public string cutoffTime { get; set; }
    public string refundInPercentage { get; set; }



}
```

Here in the data table I am unable to get the boarding points, dropping points and cancellation policy 
if I load cancellation policy as list or JObject I am getting error
so here I am loading cancellation policy as string.

but I am unable to load boarding points and dropping points.
Please help with this I am scratching my head from two days. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to convert to DataTable? If this is an ASP.NET Repeater control, as long as the object implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you can simply override the functionality of the Repeater in `ItemCreated` and place the values you want directly into the repeater via code.

Comment: I mentioned in the first line I know only one method to bind data to a repeater i.e data table . so thats why i am converting it to data table please can you help me how to bind the json data to a repeater using IEnumerable<T>

Answer (score 0):

"I know only one method to bind data to a repeater i.e data table." So this is a perfect opportunity to [learn other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674204/binding-a-generic-list-to-a-repeater-asp-net), wouldn't you say?

Why don't you work with the `result` of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);`? This is a `RootObject` that has a property called `apiAvailableBuses` which seems to be exactly what you need to bind to your `repeater`, no?

*By the way, a bit of code review:*

- `apiresult` and `apiAvailableBuses` violate Microsoft's rules WRT class names: [those should be in PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx). Same for the properties of `apiresult`, e.g. `message` and `success`. Same for the properties of `apiAvailableBuses`.
- `RootObject` has a public field: `apiStatus`. That probably needs to be a a property with a getter/setter.
- Moreover, `apiAvailableBuses` is plural, which is incorrect, since the data therein is of only one bus. Same for `boardingpoints`: the class contains data for a single point, not multiple.
- Be consistent: if you use `string`, then also use `bool` and not `Boolean`.

Comment: i couldn't get the dropping points is also json list . i couldn't retrieve the boardingpoints and dropping points

Comment: please see this and help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761269/how-to-bind-multi-level-json-data-to-a-repeater